# How to generate generic GetById(int Id) function in Linqtosql?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get Entities by using same function.

```
 public static T getById<T>(int Id)
 {
        myDataContect db = new myDataContect();
        return (from u in db.GetTable<T> where u.Id == Id select u).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

How to write valid function ? Any ideas ?

Comment: What is wrong with current?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an interface that declares `Id` property and implement it in your entities. Then you will be able to add a constraint  like this:

```
// you can figure out a better name this just for example
public interface ICommon
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public static T getById<T>(int Id) where T : class, ICommon
{
    myDataContect db = new myDataContect();
    return (from u in db.GetTable<T> where u.Id == Id select u).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>()' Iam getting this error.

Comment: @GeylaniARCA it's because of the constraint on GetTable method, you need a class constraint as well: `where T : class, ICommon`

Comment: Iam getting error for this time: Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type 'DaliGym.Helper.At.ICommon' is less accessible than 'DaliGym.Helper.At.getById<T>(int)' @Selman22

Comment: make the interface public

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ID
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class IDImpl : ID
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}

public static T GetById<T>(int id) where T : ID
{
    var myDataContect db = new myDataContect();
    return (from u in db.GetTable<T> where u.Id == id select u).FirstOrDefault();

}
```